# selecting columns using below code but getting only top row

Tags: pandas, nlp

Selecting columns using pandas but getting only top row. Using following code

```
data1=data.loc[:,'Subject':'Sub-Component']

#column names being "Subject", "Original Product Version","Software Version",   "Software Version #","Software Release","Component","Sub-Component"

data1=data.loc[:,'Subject':'Sub-Component']
```

I am expecting this would select all the columns but this is not selecting all columns and I am only getting the row names/ heads as result

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to reproduce the problem, see [mcve]? This *should* slice all rows and the columns between those two labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select specific columns, add those columns names into a list and pass that:

```
col_list = ['Subject', 'Original Sub-Component']
data1 = data.loc[:, col_list]
```

If you want to select a range of columns, use `iloc` instead:

```
data1 = data.iloc[:, 3:8]
```